# Capture from OBS dshow filters

Tags: c++, directshow, obs

I'm a C++ developer working on a 3rd party windows software.
My software streams from webcam, capture cards and external applications (vmix).
Some of our customers do not want to pay for vmix licenses anymore and want to use OBS (as camera) with our software instead of vmix.

I'm struggling to make a code that captures audio and video frames from OBS dshow source filters. I simply get no frames.
Is there any working c++ sample code showing how a 3rd party app can capture from OBS in the same way like vmix ?

Just complementing... The problem is that when trying to capture from dshow audio filter using directshow api (sample grabber filter) audio samples do not come. The method:

`STDMETHODIMP CapDShowBase::SampleCB( double sampleTime, IMediaSample * pSample)`

is never called with audio samples. Video samples come normally. I've already tried almost everything...

I think there is a bug in OBS dshow audio filter implementation.

Link to OBS forum thread:
https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/capture-from-obs-dshow-filters.114452/

Thanks a lot,
Daniel